# Char Pointer Arrays

Tags: c

I was given skeleton code that gives me a char pointer array (wordslist) with a list of words read in from a txt file. I tried to move the values to a 2D array (words). It compiles just fine but when I try to print the array, I'm just getting new lines rather than the strings.

I think the problem might have to do with pointers and specifically at line 55 but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
// Lab 10 ExTalker Skeleton Code

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ncurses/ncurses.h>


#define MAXWORDS 100
#define WORDLEN 11
#define DEBUG 0   // set to 0 to disable debug output
int readWords(char *wl[MAXWORDS], char* filename); // reads words from the file
// into wl and trims the whitespace off of the end

//modifies s to trim white space off the right side
void trimws(char* s) ;
void printWords(char* words, int wordCount, int rows, int columns);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
char* wordlist[MAXWORDS];
int wordCount;
int i,j,k=0;
int columns=5;
int rows;
wordCount = readWords(wordlist, argv[1]);

if (DEBUG) {
    printf("Read %d words from %s \n",wordCount, argv[1]);
    for (i = 0; i< wordCount; i++) {
        printf("%s,", wordlist[i]);

    }
    printf("\n\n");
}


// most of your code goes here.

if ((((double)wordCount)/columns)>((double)(wordCount/columns))){
    rows=(wordCount/5)+1;
}
else{
    rows=(wordCount/5);
}
printf("%d\n\n", rows);

char* words[rows][columns];
//char arrow[rows][columns];

//Converts the list of words to a 2D array table
for(i=0; i<rows; i++){
    for(j=0; j<columns; j++){
        if (k<=MAXWORDS){
            words[i][j]=wordlist[k];
            k++;
        }

    }
}

for(i=0; i<rows; i++){
    for(j=0; j<columns; j++){
        if (k<=wordCount){
            printf("%15s", words[i][j]);
            k++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

// initscr();
// refresh();

// printWords(words, wordCount, rows, columns);
// refresh();

// sleep(5);
// endwin();

//printf("\n%s", wordlist[0]);


}


// void printWords(char* words, int wordCount, int rows, int columns){
// int i, j, k;
// for(i=0; i<rows; i++){
    // for(j=0; j<columns; j++){
        // if (k<=wordCount){
            // printw("%15s", words[i][j]);
            // k++;
        // }
    // }
    // printw("\n");
// }
// }    

void trimws(char* s) {
int len = strlen(s) ;
int x;
if (len ==0) return;
x = len-1;
while (isspace(s[x]) && (x>=0)) {
    s[x] = '\0';
    x--;
}
}

int readWords(char* wl[MAXWORDS], char* filename) {
int numread =0;
char line[WORDLEN];
char *p;
FILE* fp = fopen(filename,"r");
while (!feof(fp)) {
    p  =fgets(line, WORDLEN, fp);
    if (!feof(fp) && p !=NULL) {
        trimws(line);
        wl[numread] = (char *)  malloc(strlen(line)+1);
        strcpy(wl[numread], line);
        numread++;
        }
    } 
fclose(fp);
return numread; 
}
```

Code: http://pastebin.com/02A8nxEq
Text File: http://pastebin.com/xk0MmkEm

Output:

> ```
> $ ./lab10-3 wordslist.txt
> 16
> ```

Comment: Please post any relevant code in your question, not off-site.

Comment: the condition here will always be false: 40:if ((((double)wordCount)/columns)>((double)(wordCount/columns))){

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer Why do you say it will always be false? If wordCount was 17 and columns was 5 it would be (17.0/5)>(double)(17/5). Which should evaluate to true because 17/5 gets truncated, right?

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Sorry about that, I figured it would be easier to refer to a specific line if it was on pastebin with visible ine nimbers. I've edited the question.

Comment: You're reading past the end of the `wordlist`. If `wordlist` has 16 words, you'll create a 4x5 array. Then you'll try to put 20 words into it in your nested `for` loops. You should stop when `k == wordcount`.

Comment: @user2649697, perhaps you are correct.  If so, I apologize for the noise.  It is difficult for me to get my mind around what you are trying to accomplish.  It would be helpful if you were to edit your question; inserting some comments concerning what each portion is working to accomplish?

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer Sorry about the confusion. I thought I was doing something wrong with the pointers but it turns out it was just a simple fix of resetting the variable k to 0. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just before you print your 2D array out here:

```
for(i=0; i<rows; i++){
    for(j=0; j<columns; j++){
        if (k<=wordCount){
            printf("%15s", words[i][j]);
            k++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

you need to reset `k` to `0`, like so:

```
k = 0;
for(i=0; i<rows; i++){
    for(j=0; j<columns; j++){
        if (k<=wordCount){
            printf("%15s", words[i][j]);
            k++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

otherwise your `if` condition will always evaluate false, and you'll never print anything, since the previous loop already used it to count how many words you have.

Comment: Ah yes, that was it. I completely overlooked that. Thank you!